# Design not updating in Interface Builder (Xcode 4.5)

Tags: ios, xcode

I am new to iOS development. I am using XCode 4.5. I have a Button and a UITableView in the storyboard when I ran the project everything worked fine but after that it stopped updating design, like I added a toolbar at the bottom of the storyboard but it is not displaying when I ran the project, I have checked everything; changing button positions, TableView positions, Clean the project and then rebuild but no effect... 
Any help would be appreciated..

```
MyViewController.h 

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h> 
@interface TweetifyViewController : UIViewController{ 
   IBOutlet UITableView *tweetsContainer;
   NSArray *tweets; 
   NSMutableData *data; 
}

- (IBAction)composeTweet:(id)sender; 
- (IBAction)viewMentions:(id)sender; 

@end
```

---

### MyViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}


- (int)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return  1;
}

- (int)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [tweets count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
        static NSString *customTableIdentifier = @"CustomTableCell";

        CustomTableCell *cell = (CustomTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:customTableIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:customTableIdentifier owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }

        cell.Name.text = [[[tweets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"user"] objectForKey:@"name"];
        NSString *At = @"@";
        NSString *AtUserName = [[[tweets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"user"] objectForKey:@"screen_name"];
    cell.userName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",At, AtUserName];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
    cell.avatar.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    cell.tweetText.text = [[tweets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"text"];

    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 120;
}


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

Comment: Probably best to show some of your code you suspect may be incorrect

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear where you have added toolbar:

> at the bottom of the storyboard

Probably toolbar was placed under the tableView, so selct it and in menu `Editor->Arrange->Send to front`.

Comment: You can see the layout  

![Here is the screenshot](http://img826.imageshack.us/img826/1678/screenshot20130126at140.png)

Comment: Looks OK. You can check also placement of springs and struts(or autolayout) in the inspector.

Comment: I have changed the color of UILabel (Timeline) but changes are not reflecting....

Comment: Can you upload storyboard to droplr(or smth alike), so I can take a look at it?

Comment: Your storyboard is fine. If you delete app in Simulator and run it again, is everything the same?

Comment: After deleting app from simulator it gives an exception:  
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'MainStoryboard' in bundle NSBundle </Users/user/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/E7BCE9ED-D5A1-46F4-86C1-1D4A487AF5BD/Tweetify.app>

Comment: OK, can you delete storyboard(use remove references) from project and add file again? Then check targets->summary tab->main storyboard should be selected your file.
P.S. When adding file, "add to target" should be checked.

Comment: I have created a new project and paste the code in it. It works! well thanks though..